# How can I filter a nested dictionary at a certain nested level?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to filter a nested dictionary a certain level, for example:

```
d = {'fruit': {'sweet': {'green': 'apple', 'red': 'tomato'}, 'bitter': {'green': 'cucumber'}}}
```

I would like to write a function `filter_at_level( d, 2, lambda r: r == 'green' )`, which would return only the following without modifying the original data:

```
{'fruit': {'sweet': {'green': 'apple'}, 'bitter': {'green': 'cucumber'}}}
```

Should I avoid recursion ? Can it be written efficiently without recursion ?

Comment: what have you tried so far?   does it not work or is it slow?  And can you clarify the question a bit?  Are you looking to return the top level element(s) only if the dictionary at level `n` contains the `target` string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import ifilter

def f(d, func, l):
    if l == 0:
        return {k: d[k] for k in ifilter(func, d)}
    return {k: f(v, func, l - 1) for k, v in d.iteritems()}

d = {'fruit': {'sweet': {'green': 'apple', 'red': 'tomato'}, 'bitter': {'green': 'cucumber'}}}

print f(d, lambda k: k == 'green', 2)
```

or if you don't want the empty elements:

```
from itertools import ifilter

def f(d, func, l):
    if l == 0:
        return {k: d[k] for k in ifilter(func, d)}
    tmp = {k: f(v, func, l - 1) for k, v in d.iteritems()}
    return {k: v for k, v in tmp.iteritems() if v}

d = {'fruit': {'sweet': {'green': 'apple', 'red': 'tomato'}, 'bitter': {'green': 'cucumber'}, 'x': {'a': 'z'}}}

print f(d, lambda k: k == 'green', 2)
```